# Pyinstaller and Microsoft SDK unable to find depthengine.so.2.0

Tags: python, c++, azure, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build an executable in linux using pyinstaller. When I run the program, I got this error:

```
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5579] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/deloader/deloader.cpp (75): deloader_init_once(). Failed to Load Depth Engine Plugin (depthengine). Depth functionality will not work
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5579] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/deloader/deloader.cpp (76): deloader_init_once(). Make sure the depth engine plugin is in your loaders path
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5579] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/deloader/deloader.cpp (186): deloader_transform_engine_create_and_initialize(). Failed to load depth engine plugin
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5579] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/tewrapper/tewrapper.c (61): transform_engine_start_helper(). Transform engine create and initialize failed with error code: 108.
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5579] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/tewrapper/tewrapper.c (68): teresult == K4A_DEPTH_ENGINE_RESULT_SUCCEEDED returned failure in transform_engine_start_helper()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5579] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/tewrapper/tewrapper.c (86): transform_engine_start_helper(tewrapper) returned failure in transform_engine_thread()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/tewrapper/tewrapper.c (313): tewrapper_create(). Transform Engine thread failed to start
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.840] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/transformation/transformation.c (637): transformation_context->tewrapper != NULL returned failure in transformation_create()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.859] [error] [t=5580] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/deloader/deloader.cpp (113): deloader_depth_engine_create_and_initialize(). Failed to load depth engine plugin
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.859] [error] [t=5580] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/dewrapper/dewrapper.c (154): depth_engine_start_helper(). Depth engine create and initialize failed with error code: 108.
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.859] [error] [t=5580] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/dewrapper/dewrapper.c (160): deresult == K4A_DEPTH_ENGINE_RESULT_SUCCEEDED returned failure in depth_engine_start_helper()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.859] [error] [t=5580] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/dewrapper/dewrapper.c (194): depth_engine_start_helper(dewrapper, dewrapper->fps, dewrapper->depth_mode, &depth_engine_max_compute_time_ms, &depth_engine_output_buffer_size) returned failure in depth_engine_thread()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.860] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/dewrapper/dewrapper.c (552): dewrapper_start(). Depth Engine thread failed to start
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.860] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/depth/depth.c (398): dewrapper_start(depth->dewrapper, config, depth->calibration_memory, depth->calibration_memory_size) returned failure in depth_start()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.866] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/depth_mcu/depth_mcu.c (359): cmd_status == CMD_STATUS_PASS returned failure in depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming()
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.866] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/depth_mcu/depth_mcu.c (362): depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming(). ERROR: cmd_status=0x00000063
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.870] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (895): depth_start(device->depth, config) returned failure in k4a_device_start_cameras()
Failed to start m_device
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.878] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (266): Invalid argument to k4a_device_get_capture(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
Failed to read a m_capture
Restarting streaming ...[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (928): Invalid argument to k4a_device_stop_cameras(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (846): Invalid argument to k4a_device_start_cameras(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
Failed to restart streaming
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (928): Invalid argument to k4a_device_stop_cameras(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (266): Invalid argument to k4a_device_get_capture(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
Failed to read a m_capture
Restarting streaming ...[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (928): Invalid argument to k4a_device_stop_cameras(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (53): k4a_device_t_get_context(). Invalid k4a_device_t (nil)
[2023-11-22 08:32:16.879] [error] [t=5394] /__w/1/s/extern/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/src/sdk/k4a.c (846): Invalid argument to k4a_device_start_cameras(). device_handle ((nil)) is not a valid handle of type k4a_device_t
```

I'm running Linux 18.04. The Azure Kinnect is version 1.4. Python 3.7. Pyinstaller is run in a conda environment. I have included the missing library inside every default paths, and added the library to the pyinstaller command, but the SDK still can't see the library depthengine.so.2.0.

I have never seen anyone with this problem, so any help would be very appreciated.